# How to pass the data one function to another function in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two functions in one controller called `changeData and apply`  .the changeData have one object that should be used in the other function ..

```
public function changeData (){
$rq=Request();

$this->request=$rq->merge(["tax"=>$rq->tax *12]);

}

Public function apply (){
 //Here I want to store $this->request in one variable called $data
}
```

Comment: You use the other class to call that class and in that way access all properties of that class

Answer (score 0):

```
public function changeData () {
   $rq = Request();
   $this->request = $rq;
   return $this;
}

public function apply (){
  dd($this->request);
 //Here I want to store $this->request in one variable called $data
}
```